# Type or namespace cannot be found in Asp.Net Core MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am making a calculator on Asp.Net Core Mvc and ran into a problem.
I have `CalcModel` and `CalcController`. Also the `IndexCalculator` view.

```
public class CalcModel
{

    public decimal FirstNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal SecondNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal Result { get; set; }
    public CalculationMethod calculationMethod { get; set; }

    public enum CalculationMethod
    {
        [Display(Name = "+")]
        Addition,
        [Display(Name = "-")]
        Subtraction,
        [Display(Name = "*")]
        Multiplication,
        [Display(Name = "/")]
        Division
    }

}
```

My Controller in which there is only an addition:

```
public class CalcController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult IndexCalculator()
    {
        return View(new CalcModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]

    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexCalculator(CalcModel model)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
        switch (model.calculationMethod)
        {
            case CalculationMethod.Addition:
                model.Result = model.FirstNumber + model.SecondNumber;
                break;
        }
        return View(model);

    }
}
```

And a my wiev:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("IndexCalculator", "CalcModel", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstNumber) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstNumber)<br />
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SecondNumber) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SecondNumber)<br />
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Result) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Result)<br />
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.calculationMethod, (Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(CalculationMethod))))
            <input type="submit" />
```

And I get the error

> Could not find the type or namespace name CalculationMethod

in this line:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.calculationMethod, (Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(CalculationMethod))))
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: `CalculationMethod` is declared inside the `CalcModel` class. So you should access it along with class name like `CalcModel.CalculationMethod` probably you'll need to add the namespace also before the class.

Comment: I just changed this line like you said @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.calculationMethod, (Html.GetEnumSelectList<CalcModel.CalculationMethod>())) And there is no more error

Comment: Tell me how to make buttons instead of a drop-down list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mat J, you can access `CalculatorMethod` enum by adding the `CalcModel` prefix due to that fact that you've declared the enum inside the class and it is a nested type of `CalcModel`.

```
Html.GetEnumSelectList<CalcModel.CalculatorMethod>()
```

All the credits go to Mat J. (I didn't noticed the type incapsulation part at first).

*If he transforms his comment into an answer, I'll remove mine*

Comment: Tell me how to make buttons instead of a drop-down list?